# Online tool to create charts from tables?

Tags: tables, bar-chart, tools, charts, online

I am wondering if there is such a tool were I can provide a table and define the type of chart and it produces a Latex code for that chart?

Thank you

Comment: I am not aware of such a tool and I follow the community for a long time. But the idea is appealing of course. There are tools for table generator though. But that does not help you here.

Comment: Have you experimented with gnuplot and csv format? With this mechanism, you can import your data in TeX –there are a package for that– and also, generate the graph. Even there are a package to write the gnuplot script inside the TeX file. Look at CTAN for those packages.

Comment: The `psgraph` environment from `pst-plot` might be of interest: it uses lists of data which can be generated  by other programs through the `\readdata` command.

Comment: @djnavas Thank you for your comment. please provide an answer with additional details and figures or links for videos if possible, thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

Yes exist a tool online. There is `Plotly` that you can use with `LaTeX`. You can see at the links: https://plot.ly/feed/?q=plottype:pie or, in general, https://help.plot.ly/LaTeX-basics/.

Here there is a generic example. You can use too `Excel`.

[image]

Comment: I have not tried it but I think it can be done. I hope I helped you. However always follow the advice of the best users. Often shortcuts do not always lead to good results.

Comment: @ Sebastiano so it's not guaranteed that it produces the latex code?

Comment: Try it. Look this: https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/plotly-graphs-with-latex

Answer (score 1):

This list on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=csv), have links to package datatool and several others. This package is well rounded and allows creation of databases using LaTeX commands and pie, scatter, line or bar plots using PGF/TikZ.

On [gnuplot homepage](http://www.gnuplot.info/), you will find a gallery, downloads, contributed scripts to produce graphs, tutorial and guides. On CTAN you find it as [gnuplot CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/gnuplot).

In case you are graphing functions with  [gnuplottex](https://ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex), you embed instructions to gnuplot inside a LaTeX document, producing a graph that will be included in the pdf.

With datatool you can manage your data **and** make the graphs using PGF/TikZ. Or you can manage your data as csv and read it directly with PGF/TikZ to make a table and a graph, or use gnuplot with the same data to produce a graph whose image you will include in your pdf as an image (see on pp. 90-97 of gnuplot manual, the instruction to plot with data on an external file.

Comment: The OP want a tool online for barchart etc.